Lost transfer, based on last year tax return from HMRC
I’m still waiting for my fix return for 2022. I’ve texted hmrc, they told me that they sent money, but I didn’t received anything.
I’ve wrote to monede customer service, and they told me that money may be at intermediary bank.
Does someone else met this problem before?
I’ll be very grateful if you’ll give me an advice

Given that a (very quick) websearch for monede didn't turn up much (other than it's a word for coin; certainly nothing that would obviously have "customer service"), my first reaction is that something scammy may be happening... you'd need to provide clearer details (what's a "fix return", where did you get the HMRC text number from) to be sure.


I’m still waiting for my fix return for 2022

By "fix return" I guess you mean "tax refund"

I’ve texted hmrc

Texting, the Short Message Service (SMS) provided by GSM phones, isn't one of the contact methods listed by HMRC.
HMRC say

HMRC will never ask for personal or financial information when we send text messages.
We advise you not to open any links or reply to a text message claiming to be from HMRC that offers you a tax refund in exchange for personal or financial details. To help fight phishing scams, you should send any suspicious text messages to 60599 (network charges apply) or email phishing@hmrc.gov.uk then delete them.

(my emphasis)

money may be at intermediary bank.

There's no obvious reason a payment would be routed through an intermediary bank. This seems like the sort of reason that a scammer would use to confuse a victim.

I would use HMRC's online service at https://www.gov.uk/personal-tax-account to check for any tax refund due to me. I would be very careful to check I was using the right URL. You might instead use their voice phone service (see contact link above)
